# Change plotly colour with hex code in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to change the colour for Plotly plot and I am wondering on how to replace the colour scheme with three hex colour code like #32a852, #3261a8, #a83259.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant("world"), 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
fig.show()
```

Comment: `color_continuous_scale=['#32a852', '#3261a8', '#a83259'],`?

Comment: Ha, stupid me. Do you want to make a solution and I can mark it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.treemap.html), `color_continuous_scale` accepts a list or string:

> color_continuous_scale (list of str) – Strings should define valid CSS-colors This list is used to build a continuous `color` scale when the column denoted by color contains numeric data. Various useful color scales are available in the `plotly.express.colors` submodules, specifically `plotly.express.colors.sequential`, `plotly.express.colors.diverging` and `plotly.express.colors.cyclical`.

```
color_continuous_scale=['#32a852', '#3261a8', '#a83259']
```

[image]